# RexExp@JS: Why /[INPUT|TEXTAREA]/.test("DIV") delivers TRUE?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check w. simple RexEx `/[INPUT|TEXTAREA]/` , whether word is INPUT or TEXTAREA, but `/[INPUT|TEXTAREA]/.test("DIV")`  delivers also `TRUE`

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Words in [character classes (`[]`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) aren't tested as if they were words. Character classes just contains a list of characters to test for.

Try this instead:

```
/INPUT|TEXTAREA/.test("DIV")
```

`[INPUT|TEXTAREA]` basically tests if the string contains any of these characters `AEINPRTUX|`.

Answer (score 1):

`[]` defines a range. Replace your [] with () and it will work better ;)

```
/(INPUT|TEXTAREA)/
```

Comment: The brackets aren't necessary, here.